# How to detect duplicate between input and output file and prevent adding duplicate items into output file by csv in python?

Tags: python

I am writing a python program to manage the user accounts in FreeRadius server.If I don't want to add any duplicate accounts in the output file (users.conf).How can I change the code in adduser command(for creating single account) and au command(for importing files to create multiple accounts)?

The username consists of 5-digit numbers in the first word in the rows.I kdon't want it being duplicated in output file after creating user account.As a changed it to be imported by csv file,how can I check the createuserentry.get() has or has not duplicated with existing username in
users.conf and stop the process if found duplicate when adding the users?

Also how to check duplicate username in csv file with comparison to users.conf and prevent adding duplicate usernames into users.conf when I import csv file to create multiple accounts?

- Preferred Output file:
- 81045 User-Password == "81045"
- 56811 User-Password == "56811"
- 56287 User-Password == "56287"
- 65654 User-Password == "65654"
- 99737 User-Password == "99737"
- 56185 User-Password == "56185"
- I don't want this output happen:
- 81045 User-Password == "81045"
- 81045 User-Password == "56811"
- 65654 User-Password == "56287"
- 65654 User-Password == "65654"
- 99737 User-Password == "99737"
- 56185 User-Password == "56185"

  ```
  def adduser():
  with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "r+") as fh:
  completed_lines = set()
  for line in open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "r"):
      if createuserentry.get() not in completed_lines:
          fh.write('\n')
          fh.write(createuserentry.get() + "     " + "User-Password == "  + '"' + createuserpwd.get() + '"')
         fh.write('\n')
         fh.close()
         tkMessageBox.showinfo("success", "Account created")
      else: continue
      fh.close()
      tkMessageBox.showinfo("Failure", "Username is duplicated")



   def au():
      au.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file to open",filetypes = (("csv","*.csv"),("all files","*.*")))
      print(au.filename)
      with open(au.filename) as input_file:
      reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
      f = open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "a+")
      seen = set()
      for row in reader:
      rows = tuple(row)
      f.write(row.get("username") + "      " + "User-Password == " + '"' + row.get("password") + '"' + "\n")
   f.close()
   tkMessageBox.showinfo("success", "Accounts created and all duplicate items are ignored")


   def deleteuser():
     with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "r") as fh:
     lines = fh.readlines()
     with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "w") as fh:
     for line in lines:                  
         if deleteuserentry.get() in line and  deleteuserpwd.get() == "Pa$$w0rd123" :
         tkMessageBox.showinfo("success", "Account Deleted")
         end()



    def du():
     du.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("csv","*.csv"),("all files","*.*")))
     print(du.filename)
     with open(du.filename) as input_file:
     reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
     f = open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', 'r+')
   for row in reader:
      rows = tuple(row)
      if row.get("delete") == "y":
         f.write(row + '\n')
   f.close()
   tkMessageBox.showinfo("success", "Accounts deleted")
  ```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code.

Comment: Please provide sample inputs. General idea is that you should be putting your data in dictionary, (keys being user since unique, values being password), then instead of doing 'delete' users, simply do a write over the original file or timestamp another file

Comment: It is the same as your previous question